# Getting the value of a specific div inside a table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, row

I have a dynamic table with data from a database.
Each row contains 4 div elements, with some text.
I would like to be able to get the value of one of those div's.

Here is a little bit of the table:

```
function addData(Dato, BookedBy, Fra ,Til) {

              var tbl = document.getElementById('bookingListe');
              var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;

              // if there's no header row in the table, then iteration = lastRow + 1
              var iteration = lastRow;
              var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

              // left cell
              var cellLeft = row.insertCell(0);
              var person = document.createElement("div");
              var dato = document.createElement("div");

              var fra = document.createElement("div");
              var til = document.createElement("div");
              var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
              checkbox.type = "checkbox";
              checkbox.name = "delete";


              dato.innerHTML ="Booket for: " + Dato;
              person.innerHTML ="Booket av: " + BookedBy;
              fra.innerHTML ="Fra: " + Fra;
              til.innerHTML ="Til: " + Til;


              cellLeft.appendChild(person);
              cellLeft.appendChild(dato);
              cellLeft.appendChild(checkbox);
              cellLeft.appendChild(til);
              cellLeft.appendChild(fra);
```

Here is the method for getting one of those divs.

```
function Slett(){
   $('#bookingListe').find('tr').each(function () {
      var row = $(this);
      if (row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')){
          alert(row.find('div').val());
        // Since there are 4 divs, the code above isn't going to work
      }
  });
 }
```

This isn't working, and Javascript isn't my strong side.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Use `.html()` or `.text()`, As `.val()` is used with input controls like textbox

Comment: Im trying to get the "dato" div btw.

Comment: Like this? alert(row.find('dato').html()); @Satpal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to add unique class to div like

```
var dato = document.createElement("div");
d.className = "dato";
```

Then you can access it using [**class selector**](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/). As `dato` is a div element you need to use [**.html()**](https://api.jquery.com/html/) or [**.text()**](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
var dataText = row.find('.dato').html();
```

Comment: @Simen_257, Great mate